# How i can show a thumbnail of a SharePoint list item attachment

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, powerapp, powerapps-forms

I have an screen which contain edit form + Image:-

[image]

The attachment inside the form only allow to upload single attachment and it will only contain Png or jpg files. now i want to show a thumbnail of the list item attachment inside the Image. this should cover 2 cases:-

1. there is no attachment already, and the user upload an attachment and did not submit the form yet.
2. the list item already have an attachment and i am retrieving the list item inside the form.

can anyone advice?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following formula to set image to achieve your both requirement (Assuming that you are customizing SharePoint List Form):

```
First(Attachments_DataCard1.Attachments).Value
```

See output below:

[image]

Comment: worked perfectly thanks